# PyPar2 pops up when i try to run eclipse. Please help

Tags: java, eclipse

I have downloaded the adt-bundle for linux and extracted it. Moved the extracted folder in "android" directory in my /home directory. I have also installed openjdk 6. So when i try to run eclipse, Pypar2 window pops up and i just don't understand how do i run eclipse.

If i uninstall PyPar2, it says 'Could not display "/home/siddhartharao17/Androi...20131030/eclipse/eclipse".' There is no application installed for executable files. Do you want to search for application to open this file?

Please help me!!

Comment: what was the command did you tried to uninstall pypar2?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the executable doesn't have the required permissions.

Simple resolution without using terminal - right-click the executable -> properties -> permissions tab. Check the checkbox that says "Allow executing file as program". Done!

Using terminal - navigate to your dir. Execute the following -
chmod 711 eclipse

Done!

Comment: Thank you so much sir for replying! And yes i did that. Also i had not placed the folder in my home directory. Now everything is fine :)